# Attributes in a SOAP request with php

Tags: php, attributes, soap-client

I'm trying to create this XML in a SOAP call

```
<ns1:NameID type="INTERNAL">831392</ns1:NameID>
             <ns1:NameMembership primary="true" displaySequence="1">
                 <ns2:membershipType>PFS</ns2:membershipType>
                 <ns2:membershipNumber>222222E</ns2:membershipNumber>
                 <ns2:membershipLevel>SILVER</ns2:membershipLevel>
                 <ns2:memberName>Luis Fernandez </ns2:memberName>
             </ns1:NameMembership>
```

I don't know how to add the `primarykey` and displaySequence` attributes. I trying to create something like this:

```
$parameters = array("NameID" => array("_" => "831392", "type" => "INTERNAL"),
            "NameMembership" => array("_" => array(
              "membershipLevel" => "SILVER",
              "memberName" => "Luis Fernandez",
              "membershipType" => "PFS",
              "membershipNumber" => "222222E"), "primary" => true, "displaySequence" => 1
        ));
```

But it doesn't work. It returns this code:

```
<ns1:InsertGuestCardRequest>
        <ns1:NameID type="INTERNAL">831392</ns1:NameID>
        <ns1:NameMembership primary="true" displaySequence="1"/>
    </ns1:InsertGuestCardRequest>
```

Can anyone help me to find what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I got it! Thanks!

```
$parameters = array("NameID" => array("_" => "831392", "type" => "INTERNAL"),
        "NameMembership" => array(
          "membershipLevel" => "SILVER",
          "memberName" => "Luis Fernandez",
          "membershipType" => "PFS",
          "membershipNumber" => "222222E", 
           "primary" => true, 
           "displaySequence" => 1
    ));
```